# Powershell сбор логов и АД

Tags: powershell

Написал я как-то скрипт на `powershell`, который цепляет эвенты принт сервера с id 307 и id 805, соответственно. Все бы и ничего, но начальству понадобилось вдруг, что б вместе с `samaccountname`, которое вытаскивается из 307 эвента прит сервера, так же из самой `active directory` бралось значение `office` и, в тот же лог, соответственно, записывалось. Вопрос: можно ли сие сделать и, если не трудно, никто не подскажет - как?
Сам скрипт:

```
$a3 =  Measure-Command -Expression { 

$workpath = "C:\parslog\logs\work" 

$logname = "306EV%" 
$logname3 = "805EV%" 
$logname5 = "printlog%" 

$logname1 = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($logname) 
$logname2 = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($logname3) 
$logname4 = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($logname5) 

$Now = [System.DateTime]::Now 
$filedate = $Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd_HH mm") 

$out_evt_file = "$workpath\$logname1-$filedate.evtx" 
$out_evt_file1 = "$workpath\$logname2-$filedate.evtx" 
$out_csv_file = "$workpath\$logname1-$filedate.csv" 
$out_csv_file1 = "$workpath\$logname2-$filedate.csv" 
$out_csv_filetogether = "$workpath\$logname5-$filedate.csv" 

#wevtutil.exe cl $logname /BU:$out_evt_file /uni:true 
#wevtutil.exe cl Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational /BU:c:\install\printaudit\work\filedate.evtx /uni:true 
wevtutil.exe Export-Log Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational C:\parslog\logs\work\filedate.evtx /ow:true 
wevtutil.exe Export-Log Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational C:\parslog\logs\work\filedate1.evtx /ow:true 

$query = "*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=307)]]" 
$query1 = "*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=805)]]" 

#$Events = wevtutil.exe query-events $out_evt_file /lf:true /q:$query /f:XML /locale:ru /uni:true 
$Events = wevtutil.exe query-events C:\parslog\logs\work\filedate.evtx /c:50/rd:true /lf:true /q:$query /f:XML /locale:ru /uni:true 
$Events2 = wevtutil.exe query-events C:\parslog\logs\work\filedate1.evtx /c:50 /rd:true /lf:true /q:$query1 /f:XML /locale:ru /uni:true 

$Events1=$Events  | 
 % { [xml]$_ } |  
 % {  

        if ($_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param7 -is [array] ) { 
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 

      JobID = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param1;  
      user = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param3; 
      comp = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param4; 
      printer = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param5; 
      port = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param6; 
      kolvo_str  = [int]$_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param7[0]; 
      size = [int]$_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param7[1]; 
            Date = $filedate; 
            } 
        } else { 
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 

      JobID = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param1; 
      user = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param3; 
      comp = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param4; 
      printer = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param5; 
      port = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param6; 
      kolvo_str = [int]$_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param7; 
      size = [int]$_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param8; 
            Date = $filedate; 
            } 
} 
} 

$Events1 | export-csv -Path $out_csv_file -NoTypeInformation -Encoding  Unicode 
$a3 

} 

$Events3=$Events2|  
 % { [xml]$_ } |  
 % {  
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
      date = $_.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime; 
     # time = $_.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime; 
      JobID = $_.Event.UserData.RenderJobDiag.Jobid; 
      copies = $_.Event.UserData.RenderJobDiag.Copies; 

} 
} 

$Events3 | export-csv -Path $out_csv_file1  -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode 


$a3 
$hash = @{} 
#Import-CSV $out_csv_file | Foreach {$hash[$_.JobID] = $_.user, $_.comp, $_.printer, $_.size, $_.kolvo_str} 
Import-CSV $out_csv_file | Foreach {$hash[$_.JobID] = $_.user, $_.comp, $_.printer, $_.kolvo_str, $_.size} 
$f2 = Import-CSV $out_csv_file1     
#$f2 | Foreach {if($hash[$_.JobID]) { $obj = "" | Select date, time, user, comp, printer, kolvo_str, size, copies  
$f2 | Foreach {if($hash[$_.JobID]) { $obj = "" | Select date, time, user, comp, printer, size, kolvo_str, copies 

        $obj.date  = Get-Date $_.date -uformat "%d.%m.%Y"  
        $obj.time  = Get-Date $_.date -uformat "%H:%M:%S"   
        $obj.user = $hash[$_.JobID][0]  
        $obj.comp = $hash[$_.JobID][1] 
        $obj.printer = $hash[$_.JobID][2] 
        #$obj.port = $hash[$_.JobID][3] 
        $obj.size = $hash[$_.JobID][3] 
        $obj.kolvo_str = $hash[$_.JobID][4] 
        $obj.copies= $_.copies 
        $obj 
}  

}|Export-CSV -NoType $out_csv_filetogether -Delimiter ";"  
Remove-Item C:\parslog\logs\work\*.evtx -Recurse 
Remove-Item $out_csv_file -Recurse ; Write-Host -f 'green' 'green' 
Remove-Item $out_csv_file1 -Recurse ; Write-Host -f 'blue' 'blue'
```

Тут значение `user = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param3` (из 307 эвента принт сервер лога) и есть по сути `samaccountname`. Как в сий лог сунуть еще и параметр office не совсем представляю. Есть некое общее представление, что нужно сделать что-то типо этого. Задать переменную, примерно так.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
$z = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase ` 'OU=rzkoren,OU=Users,OU=rzkoren,OU=Oren,OU=Regions,DC=rzk,DC=local' -SearchScope` Subtree -Properties samaccountname, office | select samaccountname, office
```

Затем ее как-то привязать к переменной `user = $_.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param3`. Не пойму, как сделать, что бы вместе с `user`, которая есть по сути `samaccountname` выгрузить в этот общий принт лог еще и значение `office`, непосредственно, из AD.. 
Запись в самом эвенте выглядит так:

> Документ 169, Печать документа, которым владеет Yasaulov.VI на
>   Oren-YASAUL, был распечатан на Oren-M525 через порт oren2-hp5. Размер
>   в байтах: 101494. Страниц напечатано: 1. Действий пользователя не
>   требуется.

Comment: А если принтер в другом офисе, какой офис выводить?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы взял сразу фильтр только включенных пользователей. Можно конечно и указать конкретную оушку поиска, но вдруг пользователь по какой то причине в нее не входит.

> $office=(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=user)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" -Properties sAMAccountName, office|where {$_.sAMAccountName -eq $user})

`(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=user)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)` - фильтр активных пользователей